# Parsing links from a table using Nokogiri

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

This is what I'm trying to do:

1. Look for a span tag with a particular inner text.
2. Get the table that follows this span tag.
3. Retrieve all the href links inside this table.

For example, I've taken the source of a Wiki page:

```
<h2><span class="mw-headline" id="Filmography">Filmography</span><span class="mw-editsection">           <span class="mw-editsection-bracket">[</span><a href="/w/index.php?title=Katie_Holmes&amp;action=edit&amp;section=10" title="Edit section: Filmography">edit</a><span class="mw-editsection-bracket">]</span></span></h2>
<table class="wikitable sortable plainrowheaders">
<caption>Film</caption>
<tr>
 <th scope="col">Year</th>
 <th scope="col">Title</th>
 <th scope="col">Role</th>
 <th scope="col" class="unsortable">Notes</th>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td style="text-align:center;">1997</td>
 <th scope="row"><i><span class="sortkey">Ice Storm, The</span><span class="vcard"><span class="fn"><a href="/wiki/The_Ice_Storm_(film)" title="The Ice Storm (film)">The Ice Storm</a></span> </span></i></th>
 <td>Libbets Casey</td>
 <td>First professional role</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td style="text-align:center;">1998</td>
 <th scope="row"><i><a href="/wiki/Disturbing_Behavior" title="Disturbing Behavior">Disturbing Behavior</a></i></th>
 <td>Rachel Wagner</td>
 <td><a href="/wiki/MTV_Movie_Award_for_Best_Breakthrough_Performance" title="MTV Movie Award for Best Breakthrough Performance">MTV Movie Award for Best Breakthrough Performance</a><br />
 Nominated–<a href="/wiki/Saturn_Award_for_Best_Performance_by_a_Younger_Actor" title="Saturn Award for Best Performance by a Younger Actor">Saturn Award for Best Performance by a Younger Actor</a>     </td>
</tr>
```

I'd like to look for the `<span>` tag with text 'Filmography' and then retrieve all the film links from the following table.

Can I do this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! When you ask a question regarding code, it's expected you'll show us the code you wrote as you attempted to solve the problem. Reduce the code to the bare minimum to demonstrate the problem you're having with it. Reduce the input data to the bare minimum also, and show us what you expect to return from the code. That helps us create solutions that meet your needs, not create things that work for us but have no relevance with the code you wrote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution using [Nokogiri#css](http://ruby-doc.org/gems/docs/s/superfeedr-nokogiri-1.4.0.20091116183308/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#method-i-css) selecting. (Probably not the most efficient way but it works)

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'nokogiri'

page = Nokogiri::HTML(open("http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Katie_Holmes&amp;action=edit&amp;section=10"))
puts page.css('span.mw-headline#Filmography').text

page.css('table').each do |tab|
  if tab.css('caption').text == "Film"
    tab.css('th').css('a').each do |a|
      puts "Title: #{a['title']} URL:#{a['href']}"
    end
  end
end


#=> Filmography
#=> Title: The Ice Storm (film) URL:/wiki/The_Ice_Storm_(film)
#=> Title: Disturbing Behavior URL:/wiki/Disturbing_Behavior
#=> .....So on
```

Comment: This is what I have been doing. But the problem with this is that even the other tables for say "TV Series", "Awards" have the same span class. So, this code is picking up those as well. I want just the films.

Comment: Its still doing the same thing. :(

Comment: Change the `text.casecmp("Film")` to `text == "Film"`. That should work.

Comment: Yea there are a bunch of methods that compare strings. That's good, you got it to work